# If a warlock's invocation states that they can use a spell without a slot does that mean they can cast the spell as often as they want?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

On page 111 of the 5E hand book the invocations Misty Visions, Mask of Many Faces, Master of Myriad Forms, and Otherworldly Leap all they that you can cast them without expending a spell slot. Does this mean the spells essentially become cantrips and I can cast them as often as I want?

Answer (score 17):

**Yes.** You must still respect all other required actions including components, cast time, etc. but you otherwise can cast it at-will. Note that some (most? all?) of these even specify that, like Visions of Distant Realms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it just seemed a bit weird having the ability to cast these spells at will given how useful they can be.

Comment: The trade off is that Warlocks only ever get up to four spell slots, and they're always highest level. So while these may seem useful, the class is very highly specialized.

Comment: four spell slots for each short rest.  If you rest at lunch and dinner each day you can have basically 12 spell slots.

Comment: Yes but ghat falls under the scope of whether or not you get that opportunity. Theres a thousand what if scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

**YES.** Basically, the idea of Warlock's Eldritch Invocations is that their knowledge allows them to gain certain spells, like alter self and disguise self, and for them to act as cantrips. Don't forget however that a lot of these require prerequisites anyway, like levels, and some require rests as well between uses..